# Cost percentages in Query Plan - seems inaccurate, am I missing something?

Tags: performance, sql-execution-plan

The query plan of a particular stored procedure is spiking (CPU, Logical Reads) based on Query Store info. Here's the plan:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Bk1PjndEF

I'm not very familiar with the tables and logic behind the stored procedure. However, one thing that struck me is that node SE_UserObjectiveStatus (using index IX_SE_UserObjectiveStatus_ObjectiveID_UserItemSCODataID) is 97% of the cost.

Yet when I run the stored procedure, and look at the logical reads, the reads on SE_UserObjectiveStatus are nothing. But the reads on
SE_Organization are 42414, and SE_UserAttempts are 84828. So, by far the vast majority of the reads in this query.

Is the 97% misleading me? Seems like I should be looking at SE_Organization and SE_UserAttempts. Any comments welcomed.

Comment: Yes, the 97% is misleading; even in the actual execution plan the cost percentages are atill the estimates of the estimated execution plan, which was based on the initial supplied parameters.  You have several table scans in the plan, I would focus on SE_Sequencing, SE_Objectives and look at the IO Logical Reads.

Comment: You also have possible non-SARGable predicates eg isnull([rds_qt_f___].[dbo].[SE_Items].[ParentItemID] which can prevent efficient use of indexes.